# Are the XBLA and PC versions of Minecraft compatible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Can players on a PC and an Xbox play together in any way? I.e. can Xbox users connect to a (modfied?) PC server, or vice versa?

Comment: Don't know for sure, which is why I'm not going to answer, but I'm going to say no.  From a Let's Play episode I saw on YouTube, I've seen Minecraft XBox described as a slightly updated version of Beta 1.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two versions are not compatible and can not be played together, especially to a modded version of PC Minecraft.

As mentioned by @MBraedley, the version that was ported is an older version of minecraft (though what I have read says it is based off of 1.6, not 1.8 beta). The matching for minecraft-360 uses Microsofts XBL systems and such, which PCs do not have access to. And a further incompatibility is that minecraft-360 is limited to a world size of 1000x1000.

Comment: It's definitely 1.6. 1.7 added pistons (which are not present, and which Mojang has said will be the next update) and 1.8 was the Adventure Update (which, again, definitely not present)

Answer (score 3):

It's not compatible *for now*. Don't forget that it has just been released and there are several updates planned by Notch and his team. I heard that Notch wanted to grant the compatibility between Xbox Live Arcade and PC games, though he doesn't know if it can be made this way. As we often say: Wait and see.

Though modding and designing your character is (will be ?) an integral part of the xbox version. (Since you can't modify the game folder on your xbox as you do on your computer)

Comment: FYI, The ports of Minecraft have to this date not been done by the mojang team and are done by an external company contracted to do them. (splitting hairs but just did not want people to get the wrong idea of who Notch's team is on this one)

Answer (score -1):

Machines that host minecraft as one of its games can not connect with other machines (With an exception of Ipads, Ipods, and Iphones; if one counts them as seperate machines, that is).

Comment: ...Not sure what you mean here.  People can play Minecraft on multiplayer servers between PCs (machines?), so either this is incorrect, or it needs better wording.