# Connect to PC server from PlayStation minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Is it possible to connect to same server from Mac/PC and PlayStation 3 (PS4,PS Vita in future)

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/are-the-xbla-and-pc-versions-of-minecraft-compatible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** The PC version of Minecraft and the console version of Minecraft cannot connect to each other. The Playstation version of Minecraft does its multiplayer over PSN. You connect directly to another player's world, rather than setting up a server. Therefore, you cannot connect to a PC Minecraft server on PS3, and vice versa.

Comment: +their different versions

Comment: @LFM Right. While technically the console version is *essentially* equivalent to I believe PC 1.3, even if it were technically possible, it would just come back and tell you "You need Minecraft version <whatever>"

Comment: @Unionhawk Its more that, They are in fact different games, they don't use the same code and the worlds render and work differently due to the limitations of games consoles. so there is no way that this can be done without having a console with full java support

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2019, the PS4 version can connect to PC servers.  Note that there are two versions of Minecraft: "Bedrock" and the older Java edition.  PS4s can only connect to Bedrock servers.

Comment: Please note that you can't connect Dedicated Servers, but you can join other users

Comment: @Lemon  what does that mean? Are you saying, if another user is on a Dedicated Server, you can join them but you cannot join Dedicated Servers, directly? I'm trying to figure out if I can run a server on my PC and then have my PS4 use it.

Comment: @gMale You can't join Dedicated Servers at all, only other friends and LAN Worlds. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/363495) that I made and answered for a way to make the PS4 think that a Dedicated Server is a LAN World.