# Can I play Mineplex on an Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console

I play minecraft on my xbox 360, and I can't seem to find a way to choose multiplayer, and fill out server info like on YouTube. Can I only play Java Edition mineplex?

Comment: I searched the Mineplex forums for the word Xbox and there were no relevant results.  I'm pretty sure the answer to this one is "No" but I can't say definitively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the XBLA and PC versions of Minecraft compatible?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/are-the-xbla-and-pc-versions-of-minecraft-compatible)

Answer (score 8):

You can't play mineplex on Xbox,

Xbox 360 MC doesn't support dedicated servers, you always have a player hosting it. so all dedicated servers are for PC minecraft.