# Can PS4 Minecraft join with PC Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I want to play Minecraft but I have one controller only. I do have a PC as well. Can I play PC and PS4 Minecraft?

Comment: You can't play pc servers via your console, and vice versa. Sorry.

Comment: That's not a duplicate. MCPE and Minecraft on PS4 are not nearly the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the XBLA and PC versions of Minecraft compatible?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/are-the-xbla-and-pc-versions-of-minecraft-compatible)

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can cross play with Switch or Xbox. Sony is hoping to bring cross platform play within an update coming to Better Together soon.

Answer (score 2):

With Minecraft Java Edition, no.
With Minecraft Bedrock (On switch, Windows 10, Xbox One), Not yet, but maybe it will happen in a future update :)

Answer (score 1):

With java, you can use a program called GeyserMC to connect some bedrock clients to java.  Not sure if it works for PS4 though.

Comment: You can’t connect to non-LAN and non-featured servers on PS4.

Comment: I belive that geyser does present itself as a LAN server as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be possible if you use that ps4 connection thing. I don't know the name but Sony mad it theirselves and with it you'll be able to play on your ps4 using your pc. Maybe you can then both play on the same ps4, one using the pc and one the actual ps4. I'm not sure if this works tough, I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

Yes, if the person on PC is playing Windows 10 Edition, and not Java Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you are on Java edition then no, but on bedrock edition, yes absolutely! Cross-platform is 100% between Xbox and PC but you might be able to play with PS4 if you sign in with your Microsoft account.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, no. Minecraft is unfortunately not cross-platform, even though it's something we've all wanted for quite some time. Or at least, that's what I've experienced.

Comment: Minecraft absoultely IS cross platform and has been for a bit.  But only with certain platforms.  Bedrock edition (originally Windows 10 edition) is cross play over PC, Switch, Android, iOS, and xbox one (I believe that's all).  It's quite frustrating that the PS4 isn't included...

Answer (score -2):

Nope, I have Minecraft on ps4, and you can’t do cross platform play, I know this may seem ironic but it’s because if they added cross platform play Sony is scared that even more differences between PlayStation and Xbox will be blurred. If you mean play on Pc using a console, it won’t work. There is a thing that you can use to play pc with a console but if you get caught you’ll get banned.

Comment: Note that console programs are only banned on some specific servers. Also, can you provide a source on the “Sony is scared that...” part? I haven’t heard of this before.

Answer (score -3):

you have to download a special router called GeyserMc ( https://geysermc.org/ )
you can search up yt videos on how to set it up ^-^

hope i helped a little!!!