# How do I cross-play on Minecraft with someone on pc when I’m on xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft of the xbox 360, but my friend plays Minecraft Java edition on pc. We want to figure out how to friend each other. I’ve already friended him by typing in his gamer tag. His account did show up and it is pending. Somehow he didn’t get it. We tried to figure out how he can accept my friend request but he couldn’t find it. Then we decided to try me joining his server except I can’t do that since I’m on the xbox 360. We just need to know how we can friend each other so we can cross-play on the same world/server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the XBLA and PC versions of Minecraft compatible?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/are-the-xbla-and-pc-versions-of-minecraft-compatible)

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually cross-play between Xbox 360 and PC, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There's no cross-play between Java Edition and Bedrock Edition. The differences in mechanics between these two are a bit too fundamental. You might get Windows 10 Edition for PC, which is one of variants of Bedrock Edition, purchase a Realm and play on that, or try setting up [Bedrock Edition server](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock/), it's in early alpha currently though, so expect serious bugs and problems.

If you bought your Java Edition before October 19, 2018, you're entitled to a free copy of Bedrock Edition. Log in to your account on http://minecraft.net to claim it.